# How to remove Wordpress Plugin free version text

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

[image]

Is there any way to remove "WordPress carousel free version" this text. 
Wonder Plugin version 12.3

You can see carousel example here http://rashedulalam.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
.amazingcarousel-image > div {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

That said, the most moral way to do it would be to pay for the paid version 
 of the plugin.  The plugin creator's time and effort were not offered to you for free unless you agreed to advertise for her.

Edit:  $49/year/site for a carousel?  highway robbery, hide away.

Answer (score 0):

Go to plugin

> wonderplugin-carousel-> engine folder-> wonderplugincarousel.js

Edit wonderplugincarousel.js file and search `wtextcssdefault` then change `opacity:0.9` to `opacity: 0`
and save.

Answer (score 0):

On the edit slider screen of the plugin click on Option tab.

Click on Advance Option and put following css in the Custom CSS box.

```
.amazingcarousel-item div.amazingcarousel-image :nth-child(3) { z-index: -99; }
```

I hope this is useful and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

With version 12.7 (mar2018) work only the last solution here above, this:

On the edit slider screen of the plugin click on Option tab.

Click on Advance Option and put following css in the Custom CSS box.

```
.amazingcarousel-item div.amazingcarousel-image :nth-child(3) { z-index: -99; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working newly updated by me

```
.amazingcarousel-image a { opacity:0 !important }
.amazingcarousel-image .wondercarousellightbox { opacity:unset !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

> wonderplugin-carousel-> engine folder-> wonderplugincarousel.js

Edit wonderplugincarousel.js file and search `wtextcssdefault` then change `opacity:1` to `opacity: 0`for each Opacity tag in that statement and at the end
change Visibility block to none, display block to none.

100% working.....